# NewConnectionError installing scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pip

Python version: 3.5.6
Platform: Xilinx Ultrascale+

I'm trying to install scipy on an embedded Linux device I have.  I've had success installing numpy, matplotlib, and urllib3 with the following command.

```
python3 -m pip install matplotlib --user --proxy <company proxy> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

But when I try to install scipy I get the following:

```
Collecting scipy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/ab/e2eb3e3f90b9363040a3d885ccc5c79fe20c5b8a3caa8fe3bf47ff653260/scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz (24.6MB)
    100% |################################| 24.6MB 18.5MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1anmecmf --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -- wheel setuptools Cython>=0.29.13 "numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='3.5' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.5' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and platform_system=='AIX'" pybind11>=2.4.0:
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting wheel
    Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9e76c160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/wheel/
    Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9e76c550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/wheel/
    Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9e76c8d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/wheel/
    Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9e76c278>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/wheel/
    Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9e76c4e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/wheel/
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for wheel

  ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1anmecmf --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -- wheel setuptools Cython>=0.29.13 "numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='3.5' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.5' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and platform_system=='AIX'" pybind11>=2.4.0" failed with error code 1 in None
```

I'm trying to figure out what is causing the 'NewConnectionError' error. I think it is trying to download more files from a site that is not in the --trusted-host list already.  Is that correct and if so, what site is it trying to go to?

Comment: Upgrade to Python-3.6 or newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with the SciPy maintainers, I've found the correct source of my problem.

The source of the problem is that something was trying to download without going through the company proxy specified in original `pip` command. I had thought at first that this was in the SciPy setup.py script. The SciPy maintainers pushed back when I flagged the issue and said that the problem is in pip. It turns out they were right. I'll quote them here:

rgommers:

> What's happening is that pip sees that SciPy has a pyproject.toml file
>   which contains build dependencies, that it then tries to download. So
>   either this is a pip bug not respecting the proxy (looks likely here),
>   or it's something in your proxy config. It is not happening in our
>   setup.py file.

The dependency that pip was trying to download was "wheel".  It even says so in the above example:

```
Collecting wheel
```

But with that package name I did not recognize what was going on. I thought that meant it was trying to download a wheel of SciPy from another location.

I was able to fix my problem by installing wheel separately:

```
python3 -m pip install wheel --user --proxy <company proxy> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

And then installing SciPy.

The version of pip I have is 18.0. Don't know if this is fixed in the latest.

Comment: Bug report accepted by the pip developers.  https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7805

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the source of the problem but there doesn't seem to be an easy solution.

When you browse through setup.py for scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz, you see that it passes download URLs pointing to GitHub into numpy.distutils.core.setup. I think that the install routines are trying to see if there is a wheel at GitHub. Notice that the connection errors happen after it says "Collecting wheel". It's never going to be able to reach GitHub unless it uses the company proxy. But I don't see a way to pass that proxy address from pip into the scipy install code. And so everything stalls.

Basically unless a wheel exists at pypi.org, which it doesn't in my case (linux on ARM), then I appear to be out of luck. Compiling my own wheel from scratch looks to be the only option.